# Use "In addition" and "while" together

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Can I use "while" after "In addition"?

> In addition, while reuniting elder parents with their migrant children seems an attractive proposition, it is so different from expectation in long term.

Is my sentence grammatically Ok?

Comment: You might add why you think there is a conflict between *while* and *In addition*.

Comment: The *"it is so different from expectation in long term"* isn't right.  (*"in long term"* has to be *"in the long term"* or preferably more like *"over the long term"*).  "it is so different" doesn't fit here either.  What you're looking for may be something more like *"In addition, while reuniting elder parents with their migrant children seems an attractive proposition, the realities over the long term may not live up to the expectations."*

Answer (score 1):

> **In addition, while** reuniting elder parents with their migrant children seems an attractive proposition, it is so different from *the* expectation in *the* long term.

*In addition* is just used to connect this statement with a previous one. It is not really related to either phrase being joined, and shouldn't result in any conflict with the words in them.

For example:

> I want to go to the beach tomorrow. **In addition**, I want to look for seashells.

Comment: Actually this sentence is a part of a longer essay. I have mentioned some statement in the previous paragraphs and i want to write a new one with this sentence.

Comment: Then you should add a previous statement to your question, as the relationship between the two statements will guide what connecting phrase you can use.